# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null

Tags: javascript

So while trying to work on this piece of code for school I keep running into this error. 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null" Essentially what I'm trying to do is in JS only, allow the user to hover over the thumbnail size picture and have it change the main picture to the corresponding thumbnail.

```
 var ImageGallery = {
  init: function(){
    picArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

    // Get reference to large image and store in variable named canvas
     ImageGallery.canvas = document.getElementById("#bigPic");

    // Set up nodelist, named thumbs, containing references to all 
    // <img> tags in div#thumbnails
    var thumbs = document.querySelectorAll('#thumbnails > img');

    // Add mouseover and mouseout event handlers to each thumbnail
    // image using a for loop.  Set them up to call a method of our     
    // object called newPic on mouse over and a method called origPic 
    // on mouse off.

    for(var index = 0; index < thumbs.length; index++){
      thumbs[index].onmouseover = ImageGallery.newPic;
      thumbs[index].onmouseout = ImageGallery.origPic;
      console.log(index);
    }},
  newPic: function(){
    // Get the value of the moused over object's id attribute and     
    // store it in a variable named imgNumber
    var imgNumber = this.getAttribute('id');


    // Build the path to the image we want to rollover to and store
    // the path string in a variable named imgPath
    var imgPath = "images/bigPics/" + (parseInt(imgNumber) + 1) + ".jpg";
    //alert(imgPath);

    // Rollover the large image to the moused over thumbnail's large 
    // image 
    bigPic = document.getElementById('#bigPic');
    bigPic.src = imgPath;
  },
  origPic: function(){
  }
};

Core.start(ImageGallery);
```

I can get the imgPath to show up when I'm using the alert to verify it works, but when I try to set the src of the main div#bigPic it just gives me the error.

Comment: It means you are trying to access something that's null; your query selector isn't finding anything. Are you sure your big picture's id is correct?

Comment: remove the `#` in `document.getElementById('#bigPic')` -- the # is a css selector and it's used in jQuery to say get the item with the ID of bigPic, but you're using plain javascript and already telling it you're looking for the element by ID

Comment: Might be because it cannot find the DOM element with id `bigPic`... Make sure you place this script at the end of the body tag or you can use `jQuery(document).ready(function(){});`

Comment: Also consider using a library like jQuery. It makes writing javascript a lot easier with its chained statements, and includes features like animation that make your site look better.

Comment: Also, you may try putting your code at the end of the body (instead of inside the head tag) in order to assure the DOM nodes will be present - if you're not using jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `bigPic` is in fact the ID of an `img` tag, you are going to want to do `document.getElementById('bigPic')` instead of using `#bigPic`.

You are mixing the CSS selector that you'd use in jQuery or CSS (i.e., `$('#bigPic')`) with plain javascript.  Using the `getElementById` function, you're already saying you're looking for something by the ID.

Comment: THANK YOU!I've been playing with jQuery for the last few weeks and what you said was exactly the problem. I didn't even think of that. I appreciate it!